# Process killed due to too much memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, swapfile

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.9.0-rc2) installation running on VMWare. I've given it 512MB RAM.
cat /proc/meminfo shows:
 
MemTotal: 507864 KB
MemFree: 440180

I want to use the swap (for some reason) so I wrote a C program which allocates a 500MB array (using malloc()) and fills it with junk. However, the program gets killed before it can fill the entire array and a message "Killed" appears on the screen.

I wanted to ask if this is normal behavior and what is the reason behind this? In my opinion, the swap should be used because the free RAM is insufficient.

Edit: I did not mention that I have 1GB swap. cat /proc/swaps shows:
/dev/sda5 Size: 1046524 Used: 14672.
The "Used" amount increases when I run the memory-eating program. But as you can see, a lot of swap is leftover. So why did the program have to be 'Killed'?

Comment: Google for `Linux memory overcommit` ; and yes it is configurable and can be disabled. BTW, you probably mean Ubuntu 12.10, the Linux kernel is at version 3.8 on http://kernel.org/ (and Ubuntu 12.10 probably has an earlier kernel). BTW, your 512Mb memory is not fully available for data: the kernel, the program, and other processes eat that memory too!

Comment: Check the `ulimit` output if 500 MB data allowed.

Comment: @ott: ulimit is showing unlimited.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: thanks! I've edited my question. I'm googling it to see if your suggestion helps.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ulimit -a`¿

Comment: If `/proc/meminfo` says you have 440MB free memory, I'm not sure how it should handle allocating a 512MB array and touching every byte of it (you mention filling it). If you are expecting it to use the swap on the host system, you'll need to rethink that and add some swap to the virtual guest as well...

Comment: @twalberg: I think the virtual machine has its own virtual swap, just like it has a virtual disk. I've added the contents of /proc/swaps to the question description.

Comment: @ott Here is ulimit -a
core file size: 0
data seg size: unlimited
scheduling priority: 0
file size: unlimited
pending signals: 3347
max locked memory: 64
max memory size: unlimited
open files: 1024
pipe size: 8
POSIX message queues: 819200
real time priority: 0
stack size: 8192
cpu time: unlimited
max user processes: 3347
virtual memory: unlimited
file locks: unlimited

Comment: I think it's the OOM killer who kill the process which take too much memory.

Comment: If it is in fact the OOM killer that pulled the trigger, there will usually be something logged about it - try `dmesg` or look at e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/kern.log`, etc. (default syslog configuration varies greatly depending on your distribution). If it's not the OOM killer, perhaps `strace ./my_application` could tell you more (or `gdb`, or ...)...

Comment: @twalberg dmesg shows "select 3089 (hog), adj 0, size 97397 to kill". And then it sends it a SIGKILL. But my main question is unanswered: why is this happening even though I have 1GB swap?

Comment: @tian_yufeng: why is 500MB too much when I have 512 MB RAM + 1 GB swap space?

Comment: Since dmesg does not show any lines containing "Out of memory", I'm not even sure if its the oom killer doing the killing :-/.

Comment: Just to make sure, is your swap space on the host (non-VMware) system, or do you have swap space configured within the guest?

Comment: @twalberg: I'm running VMWare player on Windows 7. Inside the guest, I have 1GB swap space. I've written the output of cat /proc/swaps in the question.

Answer (score 1):

So I couldn't find a valid answer. I have a temporary solution:

I had modified the Virtual Machine settings to give 512MB RAM to the VM. Now I reverted back to 2GB and ran 5 parallel programs each consuming 500MB. Thankfully, all of them run and the swap gets used.

I just needed to use the swap for a project on swap management.

Answer (score 0):

It also matters how you have written your C program to allocate the memory  and what are the compiler flags. For example, if you are statically allocating memory (such as double A[N][N]), the behaviour is different from dynamically allocating it: (such as using malloc/calloc).  Static allocations are limited by the memory model of the compiler (medium, small etc, often can be specified). Perhaps, a good starting point is :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Does this help?